# PHP strange behaviour with line comment

Tags: php

The last days I thought I was unable to write PHP code because sometimes my code didn't work. Even simple lines.

So now I found out that when I write a line comment that every new PHP code after that comment does not get executed.
For example:

```
$a = 2;
echo $a;
// let's add 2 to $a and echo it
$a = $a + 2;
echo $a;
```

Everything after that line comment won't work. But the next weird thing is that there is also no notice in the logs.

Does anyone know that behaviour or what to do to get PHP working normally again?

My PC has PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli) installed.

Comment: Is this your entire script? What is the output now? Do you have error reporting at the top `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` ? (FYI: **How do you fix stuff working in IT?** 1. 75% Restart what ever isn't working 2. 15% Quick google search 3. 10% Weird IT vooodoo) On SO we are the last 10 percentage

Comment: The case may be different interpretations of the "new line" characters. F.e. you type the text in a Windows' editor, but run on Unix.

Comment: i think it need to check apache server setting ?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko That was my first thought, but I never had problems with that and edited the same files on windows/max/unix/android and ran them on windows/unix servers. Is that actually possible without some weird settings?

Comment: @HugoDelsing I always thought that PHP is very loyal in this issue. But your case looks as if PHP doesn't recognize the end of line.

Comment: Use multiple lines comment instead

Comment: What's in your error logs?

Comment: Nothing in my error logs.
But I found the problem and edited the original Thread.

Thanks for spending time and helping me here.

Comment: @CodingHorror that is not a solution

Comment: @Tipo - write answer to your own question and set it as proper answer. therefore you will close the question^^

Comment: Post your solution as answer and accept it to close this topic.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
I found my problem.
No restart helped me.
No new installation of PHP.
I use PHPStorm and for some unknown reasons the line separator in the Cody Styles had the option "System-Dependent".
And this options causes that all new created files were saved in a single line. I first recognized it when my partner open my files on the server.

Now I changed that line separator option to UNIX and everything is fine.

But I like to know where I can find this System-Dependent configuration on my Ubuntu that causes this behaviour.